# ISA swizzling and calls to `super`

Tags: objective-c, superclass, objective-c-runtime, swizzling, isa-swizzling

Assume the following class hierarchy. Class `A` is publicly declared:

```
@interface A : NSObject

+ (A)createInstance;
- (void)a;

@end
```

Class `_B` is a private subclass of `A`:

```
@interface _B : A

- (void)a;
- (void)b;

@end
```

Assume objects of class `A` should only be created using the factory method `createInstance`, which creates and returns an instance of `_B`.

I want to enhance the functionality of an instance of `A` on a per-instance basis. So I decided to do some ISA swizzling to achieve:

```
@interface ExtA : A

- (void)a;

@end

@implementation ExtA

- (void)a
{
    NSLog("ExtA_a");
    [super a];
}

@end
```

And I do the ISA swizzling using the following method on an `NSObject` category (naive implementation shown here):

```
- (void)changeToSubclass:(Class)cls prefix:(NSString*)prefix suffix:(NSString*)suffix
{
    NSString* className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", prefix ? prefix : @"", NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(self)), suffix ? suffix : @""];

    if([className isEqualToString:NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(self))])
    {
        className = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@)", NSStringFromClass(object_getClass(self)), NSStringFromClass(cls)];
    }

    Class newSubclass = objc_getClass(className.UTF8String);

    if(newSubclass == nil)
    {
        newSubclass = objc_allocateClassPair(object_getClass(self), className.UTF8String, 0);
        objc_registerClassPair(newSubclass);

        unsigned int listCount = 0;
        Method *list = class_copyMethodList(cls, &listCount);

        for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
        {
            class_addMethod(newSubclass, method_getName(list[i]), method_getImplementation(list[i]), method_getTypeEncoding(list[i]));
        }
        free(list);

        listCount = 0;
        list = class_copyMethodList(objc_getMetaClass(class_getName(cls)), &listCount);

        for(int i = 0; i < listCount; i++)
        {
            class_addMethod(objc_getMetaClass(class_getName(newSubclass)), method_getName(list[i]), method_getImplementation(list[i]), method_getTypeEncoding(list[i]));
        }
        free(list);
    }

    object_setClass(self, newSubclass);
}
```

Everything seemingly works, but I noticed that `[super a];` does not behave as expected, actually the implementation of `-[A a]` is called, if if the superclass in runtime is actually `_B`.

Replacing the call to `super` with the following code works, but is ugly, and requires knowledge of and work by developers:

```
struct objc_super superInfo = {
    self,
    [self superclass]
};
objc_msgSendSuper(&superInfo, @selector(a));
```

What does the compiler emit when calling `super` and any way to change this emitted code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is minor, but important. The compiler is issuing a function call, not to `objc_msgSendSuper`, but to `objc_msgSendSuper2`.

What's the difference, you may ask? It's minor, but important.

From [apple's open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-646/runtime/Messengers.subproj/objc-msg-x86_64.s):

```
/********************************************************************
 *
 * id objc_msgSendSuper(struct objc_super *super, SEL _cmd,...);
 *
 * struct objc_super {
 *      id  receiver;
 *      Class   class;
 * };
 ********************************************************************/

    ENTRY   _objc_msgSendSuper
    MESSENGER_START

// search the cache (objc_super in %a1)
    movq    class(%a1), %r11    // class = objc_super->class
    CacheLookup SUPER       // calls IMP on success

/* Snipped code for brevity */

/********************************************************************
 * id objc_msgSendSuper2
 ********************************************************************/

    ENTRY _objc_msgSendSuper2
    MESSENGER_START

    // objc_super->class is superclass of class to search

// search the cache (objc_super in %a1)
    movq    class(%a1), %r11    // cls = objc_super->class
    movq    8(%r11), %r11       // cls = class->superclass
    CacheLookup SUPER2      // calls IMP on success
```

For those reading who are unfamiliar with x86_64 assembly, the important line of code is here:

```
movq    8(%r11), %r11       // cls = class->superclass
```

What does this do, you may ask? It's fairly simple - instead of the caller passing the superclass to search, the `objc_msgSend` implementation does it.

However, this important distinction causes one crucial problem - when doing a `super` call, it does **not** invoke `[self class]`. Instead, it uses the class of the current implementation, which is, of course, `ExtA`.

Therefore, the only way to 'fix' this is to change the superclass of `ExtA` at run-time, which should cause your method invoking to perform as expected.